# Elixir: pipe more then one variable into a function

Tags: functional-programming, pipe, elixir

Elixir has the possibility to pipe input into a function, which makes code more readable very often.

For example something like this

```
sentence  |> String.split(@wordSplitter, trim: true)
```

which pipes the String `sentence` into the first argument of `String.split`.

Now consider I would also like to pipe the second argument into `String.split`. Is there a possibility to do that in Elixir? I mean something like this:

```
sentence, @wordSplitter |> String.split(trim: true)
```

Thanks!

Comment: No, this syntax only works for one argument.

Comment: you can pipe a list of tuples - with the first tuple containing any arguments you want. If that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As @Dogbert pointed out, this is impossible out of the box. The helper is pretty straightforward, though:

```
defmodule MultiApplier do
  def pipe(params, mod, fun, args \\ []) do
    apply(mod, fun, List.foldr(params, args, &List.insert_at(&2, 0, &1)))
  end
end

iex> ["a b c", " "]
...> |> MultiApplier.pipe(String, :split, [[trim: true]]) 
#⇒ ["a", "b", "c"]

iex> ["a b c", " ", [trim: true]]
...> |> MultiApplier.pipe(String, :split, [])             
#⇒ ["a", "b", "c"]

iex> ["a b c"]
...> |> MultiApplier.pipe(String, :split, [" ", [trim: true]])   
#⇒ ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: Why not just `params ++ args` instead of `List.foldr(params, args, &List.insert_at(&2, 0, &1))`?

Comment: @Dogbert To demonstrate the approach. Basically, tweaking this code it’s fairly easy to embed params into any desired places of args. For reverse order, one might use `List.foldl/3` etc. For the simplest case `++` works fine of course.